# Finding and returning first column that contains data - VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to locate the first column that contains data in a given worksheet, I have seen various formulas from searching online but I am not getting the correct value. I have tried the formula from this website but it is not working.

http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=418

Any ideas?

Comment: `Range("A1").EntireRow.End(xlToRight).Column`

Comment: does this return the last column that has data? that is what happened when I tried using it.

Comment: No, it will find the first column with data in row 1.

Comment: it returned the last column that had data, any ideas?

Comment: If it returns the last column on the sheet, test to see if that has a value.  If it doesn't, the row is empty.

Comment: @antd You do not provide sufficient information to reproduce your problem. Please read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, this one is easy:

```
activesheet.usedrange.columns(1).column
```

this will give you the column number I understand you are asking for

Comment: UsedRange will include cells that have been formatted, even though they contain nothing. It's not reliable for this kind of thing.

Comment: Yes, but if you're looking for filled cells, most of the suggested methods will fail if the cells are formatted but contain no text, numbers or formulae.

Answer (score 1):

Use the End property of the Range class; this is similar to when you press Ctrl + an arrow key from an active cell. Personally I find UsedRange to be a bit unreliable because you may have used a cell unrelated to the range you're trying to find (e.g. you have a table in columns A to D and some calculations in E).

```
Dim firstColumn as Long

If Range("A1") <> "" then
    firstColumn = 1
Else
    firstColumn  = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).column
End If
```

This assumes you're likely to have data in A1. If not then do the same with columns first instead of rows, in this case using Cells instead of Range:

```
Dim firstRow, firstColumn as integer

If Range("A1") <> "" then
   firstColumn = 1
Else
   firstRow  = range("A1").End(xlDown).row
   if Range("A" & firstRow <> "" then
       firstColumn = 1
   else
       firstColumn = Cells(firstRow, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
   End If
End If
```

Comment: Dim firstRow, firstColumn as Integer creates two variables, the first a Variant, the second an Integer. You really want both to be Longs, so Dim fIrstRow as Long, firstColumn as Long would be better.  And your code returns the last row/column in any case, not the first.

Comment: @ Steve - You're right about the code following the first Else statement returning the last column so I corrected the post and yes, Long is probably better, thanks. I don't believe you're correct about declaring two variables on the same line & the the first being a variant, please provide evidence.

Comment: Try it yourself.  Put a breakpoint right after you've dimmed the variables then in the immediate window, do ? VarType(firstRow); it returns 0, meaning that it's an empty Variant.  ? VarType(firstColumn) returns 2, Integer.  Once you've assigned values to firstRow VarType will return 3, Long.  IOW, the Variant now contains a Long.

Comment: An interesting technical point but if the type is changed on assignment what's the difference?

Comment: In some situations, letting VB store whatever it thinks best can get you into trouble (and produce bugs that are very difficult to track down).  If you're going to go as far with best practices as to bother dimming variables in the first place, may as well go the distance and dim them as what you *want* them to be rather than letting VB decide what's best for you.

Comment: Well, I think one should avoid variants and undeclared variables as often as possible for performance reasons and as you say - readability, but I've learned to trust Microsoft compilers, they're pretty smart. However, to paraphrase Samuel L Jackson "If you absolutely have to be sure of every variable in the room; declare it on it's own line" ;)